# Creating a call when ready function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am relatively new to javascript and I am trying to clean up my prototype  code because it's buncha deep nested levels of callbacks and it's hard to read. I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
GoogleMaps.ready(map_id_name, function(map) {
    g_map = map.instance;
})

...

call_when_ready(g_map, set_map_viewport);
call_when_ready(g_map, create_markers);
call_when_ready(g_map, update_icons);
call_when_ready(g_map, update_geometry_display);
call_when_ready(g_map, update_ui_display);
```

I know I can move all the call_when_ready in the GoogleReady callback but this is a simplified example where `call_when_ready` is called in another callback.

so I came up with this function but it doesn't work:

```
function call_when_ready(variable, callback) {

    let interval = setInterval(() => 
    { 
        if (variable != undefined && variable != null) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            callback();
        }

    }, 3000);
}
```

The variable is always showing null even though `g_map` is being populated. How can I achieve this in a clean manner? I am open to using jQuery too but that Promise and Deffer ed seems too much for something trivial. Or maybe is there a better way for example chaining callbacks like so that I don't know about:

```
function().finished(function).finished(alert(""));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if instead of passing the variable to check, you pass a function that returns it:

```js
/* mockup */
var g_map;
var map_id_name = "example";
var GoogleMaps = {
  ready: (a, f) => {
    f({
      instance: 1
    });
  }
}

// simulate map being ready after 2.5 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
  GoogleMaps.ready(map_id_name, function(map) {
    g_map = map.instance;
    console.log("g_map set");
  });
}, 2500);

function call_when_ready(getVariable, callback) {
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (getVariable()) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      callback();
    }
  }, 2000);
}

function getGMap() {
  return g_map;
}

call_when_ready(getGMap, set_map_viewport);
call_when_ready(getGMap, create_markers);

function set_map_viewport() {
  console.log("set_map_viewport");
}
function create_markers() {
  console.log("create_markers");
}
```

Comment: you are right, this is interesting. I guess it doesn't work for my case because maybe a copy of the value is being checked instead of referencing to the original variable. maybe?

Comment: That's my guess, too.

Answer (score 2):

`g_map` is in the local scope of the anonymous function inside your GoogleMaps.ready call.

If I'm understanding your intention correctly you should move all your function calls into the anonymous function.

```
GoogleMaps.ready(map_id_name, function(map) {
    g_map = map.instance;
    set_map_viewport();
    create_markers();
    update_icons();
    update_geometry_display();
    update_ui_display();  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option would be to move the referenced functions into the `GoogleMaps.ready` function, which is, if I'm not mistaken already a callback

Comment: I actually need to call `call_when_ready` in another callback and in those function there are other callbacks again which other function depend on.

Comment: If you have a chain of functions I would say start that chain inside ready. Otherwise you need to create your own listener instead of using the one that is given to you

Comment: I am trying to look for a method to avoid chaining because I have situations where I need to wait for 3 or 4 data to be ready before calling something else.

Comment: So you have a sync requests running in parallel, and you need to know when all of them are ready?

Comment: yes and on top of that, some async functions need to start when one or more data is ready and so forth

Comment: I don't think your going to be able to easily avoid a chain of functions, but you could use getters and setters to call function when a data set is ready.

Comment: This article includes a good section on getters and setters. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146582/discussion-between-jordan-cauley-and-armenb).